# how to prevent IDM (internet download manager) to download song, song link is given in anchor tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wavesurfer.js

I'm making audio player using wavesurfer.js. I have made an anchor tag and put the song link in anchor's href attribute like this.

```
<a href="songs/song5.mp3" class="btn songlink songBtn"><i class="fa fa-play fa-lg playbtn"></i></a>
```

Everything is working fine but if I install [IDM]. It starts downloading the song and songs doesn't play on the browser. So where should I put the song link in order to prevent the downloading.

here is my jQuery code and html code is as given above

```
$(".player-playlist .songlink").click(function(){
                songLink = $(this).attr('href');
                wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
                    container: '#playing-wave',
                    waveColor: '#CCCCCC',
                    progressColor: '#E64C51',
                    barWidth:1,
                    height:40,
                    barGap:0,
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    cursorColor: 'transparent',
                    plugins: [
                        WaveSurfer.minimap.create({
                            container: '#wave-minimap',
                            waveColor: '#CCCCCC',
                            progressColor: '#E64C51',
                            barWidth:1,
                            height:30,
                            barGap:0,
                            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                            cursorColor: 'transparent',
                        })
                    ]
                });

});
```

Comment: Did you find out how to fix this issue?

Comment: I have this issue too, if u have find any solution, I would be glad to hear it